# Enviar mensaje de whatsapp con php

Tags: php, javascript, whatsapp

Amigos estoy en el desarrollo de un sistema en el cual se tiene que realizar una notificación por whatsapp, para esto he buscado en la internet y he encontrado lo siguiente

`https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=numerodetelefonodewhatsapp&text=urldelmensaje`

Si bien esto es valido para el envió de un mensaje, no es lo mas indicado para múltiple envíos, verán esto abre en el navegador una ventana de whatsapp web lo que permite enviar un mensaje al destinatario, un ejemplo del problema que tengo es en cuando tiene que enviar a múltiples destinatario y con diferencia de mensaje, es decir se tiene dos grupos A y B, dentro del grupo A existen 20 números y dentro del grupo B 10 números, en el grupo A de los 20 solo 8 se le envian una notificacion de exito y al resto una de rechazo.

Abrir una ventana por cada numero de telefono no como que viable, alguien conoce alguna forma de realizar esto, de poder enviar multiples mensajes de whatsapp o de alguna forma que no se abra una nueva ventana de whatsapp web para asi poder meter eso dentro de un ciclo y que envie los mensajes a diestra y siniestra jajajajay

Les agradezco su ayuda..

**NOTA:** Estoy realizando esto con php, pero si existe alguna forma de realizar el envió de whatsapp con javascript no importa eso se implementa de alguna forma

Comment: Esto me funciono https://www.whatsapp.com/business/api

Answer (score 0):

lo mismo que quieres hacer tu me lo propuse unas cuantas semanas atras, pero me encontré con que no había una forma formal de hacer esto, no podía utilizar y manipular a mi antojo el link de enviar mensaje.

Ahora bien, hay una opción que te da whatsapp y que con la cual debes tener experiencia en `API REST` y `.json` para poder desarrollar una web en php que te permita enviar mensajes desde tu código php a cualquier usuario de tu libreta de contactos, te recomiendo entrar en : https://www.whatsapp.com/business/api

ahí podras ver toda la Documentación para el desarrollo de la `API`, es la única forma posible de hacerlo, Saludos.

Answer (score -2):

```
href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+numerowhatsapp&text=aqui va el mensaje que deseas no importa los espacios&source=&data=&app_absent="
```

Pon este código como link al icono o al número que deseas redireccionar al WhatsApp web y listo.